# Посоветуйте БД для .net (WPF), удовлетворяющий требованиям

Tags: база-данных, .net

Просьба посоветовать БД для .net (WPF). Реализую БД для логистов (табличек 20 (перевозчики, город, логисты, типы машин и прочее), пользователей около 30, база на сервере, все подключаются через клиентские машины по локалке)
Хорошо бы удовлетворять следующим критериям: 
1 - Многопользовательская
2 - Переносимая
3 - Бесплатная

Реализовал на SQLite + Entity framework. Все чудесно работает, но только на одном клиенте, при подключении 2+, начинает страшно тормозить при обращении к базе. Перепробовал все, найти узкое место не могу. Теперь думаю реализовать на чем-нибудь еще.

Возможно не с той стороны захожу, прошу совета, сам самоучка.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: попробуйте Oracle XE, размер до 10 Гб, бесплатная, многопользовательская

Comment: MS SQL Express (не забудьте сетевые протоколы включить) или Postgre (в последнее время активно используем, даже на высоконагруженных проектах - полет нормальный). И для одной и для второй есть провайдеры для EF.